Polars Time Series Path Dependent Event Outcome calculation
In the demo DataFrame I have three events:
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        "threshold": [8, None, None, None, 5, None, None, 8],
        "value": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "event": [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        "start_ts": [1, None, None, None, 5, None, None, 8],
        "end_ts": [6, None, None, None, 8, None, None, 8],
        "event_id": [0, None, None, None, 1, None, None, 2],
    }
).with_columns(pl.col("end_ts").sub(pl.col("start_ts")).alias("event_span"))

print(df)

out:
shape: (8, 8)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┬────────┬──────────┬────────────┐
│ timestamp ┆ threshold ┆ value ┆ event ┆ start_ts ┆ end_ts ┆ event_id ┆ event_span │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---        │
│ i64       ┆ i64       ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64      ┆ i64    ┆ i64      ┆ i64        │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════╪════════╪══════════╪════════════╡
│ 1         ┆ 8         ┆ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ 1        ┆ 6      ┆ 0        ┆ 5          │
│ 2         ┆ null      ┆ 3     ┆ 0     ┆ null     ┆ null   ┆ null     ┆ null       │
│ 3         ┆ null      ┆ 4     ┆ 0     ┆ null     ┆ null   ┆ null     ┆ null       │
│ 4         ┆ null      ┆ 5     ┆ 0     ┆ null     ┆ null   ┆ null     ┆ null       │
│ 5         ┆ 5         ┆ 6     ┆ 1     ┆ 5        ┆ 8      ┆ 1        ┆ 3          │
│ 6         ┆ null      ┆ 7     ┆ 0     ┆ null     ┆ null   ┆ null     ┆ null       │
│ 7         ┆ null      ┆ 8     ┆ 0     ┆ null     ┆ null   ┆ null     ┆ null       │
│ 8         ┆ 8         ┆ 9     ┆ 1     ┆ 8        ┆ 8      ┆ 2        ┆ 0          │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────┴──────────┴────────┴──────────┴────────────┘


timestamp is the timestamp in the real world.
threshold is the value that every events' value need to achieve, or exceed during the event span.
value is the value at each timestamp, we can have duplicated values.
event is a binary column indicating whether a certain timestamp generates event.
start_ts is the starting timestamp of an event. For example, a start_ts of 1 means that the event will start at the end of timestamp1, at the beginning of timestamp2
end_ts is the ending timestamp of an event.
event_id is a unique identifier for each event.
event_span is the number of timestamp that an event spans.

Problem:
I want to identify:

event outcome: binary value indicating whether the threshold of each event is reached by value during each event span.
event outcome timestamp: the timestamp where the first time of value reaching threshold

Additional Note:

Event 0 spans [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], event 1 spans [6, 7, 8], and event 2 spans nothings.
The events would not span beyond the data that we have here (e.g., end_ts <= timestamp)

Desired Output:
shape: (8, 10)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────┬───┬──────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┐
│ timestamp ┆ threshold ┆ value ┆ event ┆ … ┆ event_id ┆ event_span ┆ event_outcome ┆ event_outcom │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆   ┆ ---      ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ e_timestamp  │
│ i64       ┆ i64       ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆   ┆ i64      ┆ i64        ┆ i32           ┆ ---          │
│           ┆           ┆       ┆       ┆   ┆          ┆            ┆               ┆ i64          │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══╪══════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 1         ┆ 8         ┆ 2     ┆ 1     ┆ … ┆ 0        ┆ 5          ┆ 0             ┆ null         │
│ 2         ┆ null      ┆ 3     ┆ 0     ┆ … ┆ null     ┆ null       ┆ null          ┆ null         │
│ 3         ┆ null      ┆ 4     ┆ 0     ┆ … ┆ null     ┆ null       ┆ null          ┆ null         │
│ 4         ┆ null      ┆ 5     ┆ 0     ┆ … ┆ null     ┆ null       ┆ null          ┆ null         │
│ 5         ┆ 5         ┆ 6     ┆ 1     ┆ … ┆ 1        ┆ 3          ┆ 1             ┆ 6            │
│ 6         ┆ null      ┆ 7     ┆ 0     ┆ … ┆ null     ┆ null       ┆ null          ┆ null         │
│ 7         ┆ null      ┆ 8     ┆ 0     ┆ … ┆ null     ┆ null       ┆ null          ┆ null         │
│ 8         ┆ 8         ┆ 9     ┆ 1     ┆ … ┆ 2        ┆ 0          ┆ null          ┆ null         │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────┴───┴──────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┘

My current solution involves generating the full path values of each event, which is highly resource intensive, especially when the events overlap with each other:
event_df = (
    df
    .filter(pl.col("event") == 1, pl.col("event_span") > 0)
    .with_columns(
        pl.int_ranges(pl.col("start_ts")+1, pl.col("end_ts")+1) # Map event full path
        .alias("event_timestamps")
        )
    .explode("event_timestamps") # Generate event full path
    .drop(pl.col("value"))
    .join(
        df
        .select(pl.col("timestamp"), pl.col("value"))
        .rename({"timestamp": "event_timestamps"}), 
        on="event_timestamps", how="left") # Get the value of the full path
    .with_columns(# Map event outcome based on threshold
        pl.when(pl.col("value") >= pl.col("threshold"))
        .then(1)
        .otherwise(None)
        .alias("event_outcome")
        )
    .with_columns(# Get event outcome timestamp
        pl.when(pl.col("event_outcome") == 1)
        .then(pl.col("event_timestamps"))
        .otherwise(None)
        .alias("event_outcome_timestamp")
        )
    .with_columns(# Map event outcome to the event start timestamp
        pl.col("event_outcome", "event_outcome_timestamp")
        .fill_null(strategy="backward")
        .over("event_id")
        )
    .unique("event_id")
    .sort("event_id")
    .with_columns(# Take care of the events that have not exceeded the threshold
        pl.when(pl.col("event_outcome").is_null())
        .then(0)
        .otherwise(pl.col("event_outcome"))
        .alias("event_outcome")
        )
    .select(pl.col("event_id", "event_outcome", "event_outcome_timestamp"))
    )

event_df
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
│ event_id ┆ event_outcome ┆ event_outcome_timestamp │
│ ---      ┆ ---           ┆ ---                     │
│ i64      ┆ i32           ┆ i64                     │
╞══════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════════════╡
│ 0        ┆ 0             ┆ null                    │
│ 1        ┆ 1             ┆ 6                       │
└──────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────┘

df = df.join(event_df, on="event_id", how="left")


Polars recently released inequality joins with join_where, which is great for scenarios with timespans like this one.
aggregated = (
    df.join_where(
        df,
        # event starts after start_ts, and goes until end_ts
        pl.col("timestamp_right") > pl.col("start_ts"),
        pl.col("timestamp_right") <= pl.col("end_ts"),
    )
    .group_by("event_id")
    .agg(
        event_outcome=(pl.col("value_right") >= pl.col("threshold")).any().cast(pl.Int32),
        event_outcome_timestamp=(
            pl.col("timestamp_right")
            .filter(pl.col("value_right") >= pl.col("threshold"))
            .min()
        ),
    )
)
# aggregated
# shape: (2, 3)
# ┌──────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────────────┐
# │ event_id ┆ event_outcome ┆ event_outcome_timestamp │
# │ ---      ┆ ---           ┆ ---                     │
# │ i64      ┆ i32           ┆ i64                     │
# ╞══════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════════════╡
# │ 0        ┆ 0             ┆ null                    │
# │ 1        ┆ 1             ┆ 6                       │
# └──────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────────────┘

df.join(aggregated, on="event_id", how="left")
# same as desired outcome

Have a look at the result of aggregated after the join_where, before the group_by to get a better understanding of how it is working

Very nice. I wonder how much of a difference putting pl.col("value_right") >= pl.col("threshold") into the join_where predicate would make.

Thanks! Unfortunately this won't join event_id 0, which is helpful in differentiating between event_outcome = 0 (event_id 0) and event_outcome = null (event_id 2).
Could certainly be done though - would just need another with_columns to fill nulls on event_outcome when event_span > 0 following the left join back to the original df.
Given pl.col("value_right") >= pl.col("threshold") is repeated in the agg context, I did also consider putting it in a variable up the top

Thank you both for the solution and comments. I wonder if adding pl.col("value_right") >= pl.col("threshold") to the join_where method would significantly reduce the RAM usage? Can we also limit the number of observations that returns, from join_where (e.g., if the threshold is pretty low, which would result in the entire path of events gets returned, but we only need the first one of every event_id)

Whether there is any material impact to RAM usage by adding the extra condition to the join_where depends on your data. Give it a go, measure it and make decide from there. I don't know of any way to further limit what join_where returns without extra understanding of the context, or resorting to heuristics or approximations (which would also require more domain knowledge). Based on the example, the event_outcome_timestamp could be the maximum of all the joined rows - there is not really a way to know without actually doing the join.

Since the Polars 1.13.0, the join_where above can be simplified even more using the range predicate is_between.
